# Why is my Red black tree search function not working?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have to create and complete functions for a red black tree. The search function in particular is a major headache because it keeps giving me this error:

```
  File "C:\Users\YOLO246\Desktop\2211 Assignment 2\Code\rbtree.py", line 135, in insert
    (wasFound, node) = self.search(key)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Can someone please assist me?

```
#!/bin/python

### Module that implements a Red-Black Tree

BLACK = 1
RED = 0

class RBTree:

    class Node:
        """Nodes specific to this RBTree.  Nodes point at trees and trees
        point at nodes.  This will allow rotations that change the
        root.

        """
        def __init__(self, parent, key, value, colour=RED, sentinel=None):
            self._parent = parent
            self._key = key
            self._value = value
            self._colour = colour
            self._left = sentinel
            self._right = sentinel

        parent = property(fget=lambda self: self._parent,
                          doc="The node's parent")
        @parent.setter
        def set_parent(self, p):
            self._parent = p

        key = property(fget = lambda self: self._key,
                       doc="The node's key")
        @key.setter
        def set_key(self, k):
            self._key = k

        @property
        def value(self):
            """The value associated with this node's key"""
            return self._value

        @value.setter
        def set_value(self, v):
            self._value = v

        colour = property(fget=lambda self: self._colour,
                          doc="The node's colour, RED = 0, BLACK = 1")

        @colour.setter
        def set_colour(self, c):
            self._colour = c

        left = property(fget=lambda self: self._left,
                        doc="The node's left child")
        @left.setter
        def set_left(self, l):
            self._left = l


        right = property(fget=lambda self: self._right,
                         doc="The node's right child")

        @right.setter
        def set_right(self, r):
            self._right = r


        def __str__(self):
            return ("<value: %s, colour: %s,%n  parent: %s,%n  left: %s,%n  right: %s%n>" %
                    (self.key, self.colour, 
                     self.parent, self.left, self.right))

    ## --- Start of RB-Tree methods ---

    def __init__(self):
        self._NIL = list()
        self._root = self._NIL

    NIL = property(fget=lambda self: self._NIL, doc="Constant sentinel NIL")
    root = property(fget=lambda self: self._root, doc="The current root node")

    @root.setter
    def set_root(self, r):
        self._root = r

    def isRoot(self, node):
        return self.root == node

    def search(self, key):
        """Returns a tuple in the format (Found?, Node).  The first part of
        the tuple is True if the node was found and False
        otherwise. The node component of the result is the node
        containing key if it was already present, otherwise returns the
        node that would be the parent of where key would have been
        found in the tree.  (This latter choice of returned node
        avoids having to search the tree twice when inserting a new
        key into the tree)

        """
        parent = self.NIL
        curr = self._root
        while curr != self.NIL:
            # Implement the rest of this loop body below
            if key == curr.key:
                return (True, curr)
            elif key < curr.key:                                    
                 parent=curr.left          # code missing
                 curr=parent
            else:
                 parent=curr.right           # code missing
                 curr=parent
            return (False, parent)
```

Comment: You should step through this with a debugger.  It will be pretty obvious when you hit the return False, no matter what, on the first step (unless they search for the root key itself).  Possible indentation error.  I also think you're confusing parent and curr in the loop, but since there is no loop, I guess that doesn't matter :)

Comment: Thanks mate I'll try your suggestion and see what happens